# looping through a dictionary of dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary, dataframe

First of all, I wrote this function:

```
def writing_in_excel(path, df, sheet_name):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, datetime_format='m/d/yyyy')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheet_name, index=False, freeze_panes = (0,1))
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```

Then, I have a dictionary of dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd    

employee = {'EmployeeID' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
     'FirstName' : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'],
     'LastName' : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'],
     'favorite_color' : ['red','blue','green','yellow','red','red','green','blue','green','red']}

df = pd.DataFrame(employee)

by_color_df_dict = dict(tuple(df.groupby('favorite_color')))))
```

In 'favorite_color', there are 4 different values, I wanted to create separate dataframes by the 4 values in 'favorite_color'

If you run that code, you will get a dictionary of dataframes as a result.  I want to loop through the dictionary and save each dataframes as an excelfile using the function that I defined above.

I think I have to start with:

```
for key, value in by_color_df_dict:
```

but I can not proceed further with my shallow knowledge.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Please share some sample data to work upon

Comment: I edited the question with the sample data

Comment: What's your expected output? Add that as well in the Question

Comment: done :) Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do

```
for color_name, group in df.groupby('favorite_color'):
    writing_in_excel('file_name.xlsx', group, color_name)
```

Comment: i only get one excel sheet with the last color. I think it is overwriting eachother

Comment: Maybe it's a better idea to save them in different files, something like `writing_in_excel('{}_file.xlsx'.format(color_name), group, color_name)`

Comment: or defining the writer outside the function.

Comment: got it. Thank you so much